# Magento condition for specific page

Tags: magento

In Magento I'm using `<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>` to check if it's the main page or not but how would I check if the user is on a custompage? **CMS Page Url Key** `game-store`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the URL key / identifier of any CMS page in Magento, use the following bit of code.

```
<?php

$yourUrlKey = 'game-store';
$cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($yourUrlKey == $cmsPageUrlKey){
     //do something here
}

?>
```

The above code will print your `URL Key`

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('game-store','identifier');
var_dump($model->getData());
var_dump($model->getPageId());
```

or

```
$model = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
->addFieldTofilter('identifier','game-store')
->getFirstItem();
var_dump($model->getData());
var_dump($model->getPageId());
```

should do it.